# How to add a dynamic class in knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let's say i have,

```
<span class="cls1 cls2" data-bind="title: title" ></span>
```

I want to add another class via JSON object,

```
{ title: 'a', clas: 'cls3' }
```

This work's,

```
    <span class="cls1 cls2" data-bind="attr:{title: title,'class': 'cls1 cls2'+clas}" ></span>
```

But the problem is that it will add two class attributes. I need the cls1 and cls2 class on beginning. But need cls3 class after some event.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that demonstrates the use case?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your example

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should use `css` binding instead of `attr` for this. Read more about it in the documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html.

You code will look something like this:

```
<span class="cls1 cls2" data-bind="text: title, css: myClass" ></span>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/gKaRF/

Comment: They recently updated UI I also had such problem. I have to clear browser cache for this site(Press Ctrl + R).

Answer (score 20):

**Using multiple classes:**

```
<span
    class="yourClass"
    data-bind="css: { myClass: (true == true), theirClass: (!true == false), ourClass: true }"
>Thine Classes</span>
```

Comment: This helped me out a bunch! Thanks

Comment: Why on earth are you doing `(true == true)` and `(!true == false)`?

Comment: @ErikE, those are just assertions. It could be something like css: { 'active-class': (isSelected == true) }

Comment: `{'active-class': isSelected}` you mean. I hope.

Comment: Sure. Either syntax will work, but having == true is rather redundant. If I were writing into an app -- not demonstratively -- then I would be writing it the way you just mentioned.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `css` binding to do this:

```
<span class="cls1 cls3" data-bind="css: clas"/>
```

This adds the value of your "clas" property to the current class collection of the element

Comment: Nice, need this for somthing line `css: 'size' + Array.length`

Comment: you can create a computed propery called "sizeClass" that returns this combination and then use it as a normal property in the css databinding

Comment: Yes, but I do not like markup decisions in my ViewModel, so using the suggested approach was perfect for me..

Comment: NOTE: CLAS IS NOT A TYPO, using css: class does not work, maybe class is a reserved keyword?

Comment: @Andrew yes, because KO also has a `class` binding. If you want to add "class" as the name of one, put between apostrophes like `'class'`.